# Stub/mock propTypes for testing

Tags: reactjs, testing, sinon, enzyme, prop

I have what seems to be a simple problem. Code works fine and everything is great but when I test component I get this warning

> Failed prop type: Controls: prop type
>   `onStatusChange` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from
>   React.PropTypes.in Controls

If I remove .isRequired from onStatusChange I get no warning. How do I test the component but leave the isRequired? Why don't I get the same error for countdownStatus prop where we pass string from the parent?

Inside my **child** Controls component I have a code like this. I am expecting to get two props, a string and a function.

```
class Controls extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    countdownStatus: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onStatusChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }
...
}
```

Inside **parent** component I have this. As you can see I am passing to my child two props, a string and function.This prop function can be called from inside child component and it will call handleStatusChange inside parrent component.

```
...
handleStatusChange = (newStatus: string) => {
    this.setState({
      countdownStatus: newStatus
    })
  }

  render (): React.Element<any> {
    const { count, countdownStatus } = this.state
    const renderControlArea = (): any => {
      if (countdownStatus !== 'stopped') {
        return <Controls countdownStatus={countdownStatus} onStatusChange={this.handleStatusChange} />
      } else {
        return <CountdownForm onSetCountdown={this.handleSetCountdown} />
      }
    }
    ...
```

**child component test.**
I use tape, enzyme, sinon.
I don't even use that prop for the test, I just shallow render the whole component.

```
test('Controls => should render pause button when countdownStatus equals started', (t: Object) => {
  t.plan(1)
  const wrapper: Object = shallow(<Controls countdownStatus={'started'} />)
  const pauseButton = wrapper.render().find('.btn-info').length
  t.equal(pauseButton, 1)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I just needed to pass empty dummy function as a prop while testing.

```
test('Controls => should render pause button when countdownStatus equals started', (t: Object) => {
  t.plan(1)
  const wrapper: Object = shallow(<Controls countdownStatus={'started'} onStatusChange={() => {}}/>)
  const pauseButton = wrapper.render().find('.btn-info').length
  t.equal(pauseButton, 1)
})
```